# Error caused by Entity name in Spring Boot RESTful API

Tags: java, spring-boot

The time when I made a User.java as an Entity, I encountered an error(The error written below). But I changed the name User.java to UserEntity.java and then an error is solved. Why just change the Entity name this error is solved.

error

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "create table [*]user (userid bigint generated by default as identity, user_name varchar(20), primary key (userid))"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
```

`Entity`

User.Java

```
package com.example.demo.rest;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty("userId")
    private Long userId;
    
    @JsonProperty("userName")
    private String userName;

}
```

`application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName:org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.datasource.username:sa
spring.datasource.password:
spring.h2.console.enabled:true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER

springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
```

`build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because USER is a reserved word (keyword) in H2 database.

Check here for the full list of H2 keywords: https://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#keywords